# Querying FB Graph API feed with fields parameter?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

what happens when a Facebook page is queried for its feed with Facebook Graph API (JS SDK) and a URL parameter `fields` (like for the `post` object) is added?

I would like to load from the feed only the posts id's, shares, likes and comments, because the page is pretty active and the text data in JSON for 2 days is about 2MB (25 items)...

I would hope one could do like this: `FB.api('/SomePage?fields=id,shares,likes')`, but I suppose the only fields you can access are the direct children (for `feed`, that is `data` & `paging`)? If this unfortunately is the case, is there any other way to retrieve all posts from date x to date y without downloading the entire feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not correct. The `feed` edge is basically an array of Post objects. You can use the Field Expansion together with time pagination as follows:

```
GET /{page_id}/feed?fields=id,shares,likes.summary(true)&since={start_unix_timestamp}&until={end_unix_timestamp}
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed/#read
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#fieldexpansion
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the nestable fieldexpansion options! Unfortunately I will have to make individual API calls for posts anyway with the paging set.

Comment: Why do you have to call individual Posts?

Comment: Because I need all the likes and comments on a post, but it only gives you the 25 first items. So I have to make more calls for the likes,eg `/{post-i}/likes?after=...`